# How to create set of div blocks using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to AngularJs. I need to create set of div blocks (given as code) on button click.

```
<div>
     <div>Div A</div>
     <div>Div B</div>
     <div>Div C</div>
</div>
```

I have done this using hard coded divs [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yXaYb/1/). But I just need to use `ng-repeat` and `directives`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hard coded divs ? From input ? More info please..

Comment: no divs cannot be hard coded. it needs to be created from templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-click` is the way to go for binding the click event to your button. You should not be trying to handle button clicks with a directive. The demo you have is very close to what you need. There is a working [Plunk HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/p8PmKf?p=preview), but the general guts of it follow:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction()">Add</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in myList">
    <div>{{item.A}}</div>
    <div>{{item.B}}</div>
    <div>{{item.C}}</div>
</div>

$scope.myList = [];
$scope.myFunction = function(){
    var myItem = {A:someValue, B:someOther, C:someThing};
    $scope.myList.push(myItem);
};
```

The divs that hold the items could also make use of directives to change them somehow, but that is quite a bit more code. There are plenty of SO answers and Angular documentation that show you how to write directives, so I won't repeat them here.

Comment: Really, i dont understand your point. Can you give me any sample?